# Find a basis of $\text{Im}(f)$ (matrix, linear mapping)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 &-1\\ 
> -1& 0 &-2\\  1 & 1 &1 \end{pmatrix}$ is a real matrix and $f: \mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}, f(x)= A \cdot x$ is the
>   linear mapping given by A. Find a basis of $\text{Im}(f)$.

This is a task from a test-exam (if you want I can send you the PDF) and I'd like to know how it's solved correctly.

---

So I started by trying to find the image first. I have taken the matrix $A$, transposed it, used Gauss to create as many zero lines as possible, transposed back and here is what I got after these steps:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0\\ 
3 & 0 & 0\\ 
-1& 4 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

We now can see the image of matrix A, it is $$\text{Im(A)}= \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
3\\ 
-1
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
2\\ 
0\\ 
4
\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$

But in task Im(f) was asked, could I simply take what I have just written above and add "$\cdot x$" at each vector?

This is the step where I don't know how to continue. I hope I did it correctly till here at all..

How would you solve this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if the vector $(1,3,-1)$ is in the range of the matrix. I can't find a solution to:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3 & -1\\
-1 & 0 & -2\\
1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$

The same applies to $(2,0,4)$.

However if you take the twice the first column minus the second you get the third. Which mean that we can immediately discard the third as being part of the base. Furthermore we see that the first and second column are obviously not linearly dependent. So a base for the range of $A$ would be $(1,-1,1)$ and $(3,0,1)$.

Apart from that I think you're pretty much done. The range of the matrix is the same as the range of the function $f(x) = Ax$. Note that the question was to give a basis (ie a set of base vectors) for the image and not determine the image itself. The answer is:

$$\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}3\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}
\right\}$$

The actual image is the space this basis spans that is $\{ s(1,-1,1)+t(3,0,1): s,t\in\mathbb R \}$.

Note that I use here mixes the compact notation $(x,y,z)$ for vectors, but you can use column matrices instead if you wish.

Comment: Thanks! I re did all the steps and in the end I get to the same "base for the range A" as you.  But what is the answer to question now? It was asked to specify a basis of Image(f)

Comment: basis of $\text{Image(f)}= \left\{\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
-1\\ 
-1
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
3\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}\right\}$?

Comment: @cnmesr No, you have the wrong sign in the lower left corner. Otherwise note that the set is the basis (which was what was asked for) for the image and not the image itself.